# MySQL Foreign Key Values

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a database called `Musicology` containing two tables `TRACKS` and `ALBUM`:

```
+----------------------------------+
|              TRACKS              |
+----------+------------+----------+
| TRACK_ID | TRACK_NAME | ALBUM_ID |   /* ALBUM_ID: foreign key from  table ALBUM */
+----------+------------+----------+

+--------------------------------------+
|              ALBUM                   |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| ALBUM_ID | ALBUM_NAME | RELEASE_DATE |   /* ALBUM_ID: primary key */
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

Since `ALBUM_ID` is a primary key of `ALBUM` and a foreign key of `TRACKS`, is it possible that `ALBUM_ID` will show `ALBUM_NAME` instead?

Like for example:

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| TRACK_ID | TRACK_NAME | ALBUM_ID |
+----------+------------+----------+
| 0000001  | HELLO      | 000001   |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

Since `ALBUM_ID` is a primary key, it can identify other columns on its table.

Can I have `ALBUM_NAME` displayed instead of `ALBUM_ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select and display track details with album name, you can write query as below:

```
Select t.track_id,t.track_name,a.album_name from TRACKS t 
LEFT JOIN ALBUM a ON a.album_id = t.album_id;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thaanks! I'll try this one immediately. :)